# Can the map function supplied to `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(...)` resolve a tensor object?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I'd like to create a `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(...)` dataset. I need to pass in a Python `generator`.

I would like to pass in a property of a previous dataset to the generator like so:

```py
dataset = dataset.interleave(
  map_func=lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=lambda: gen(x), output_types=tf.int64),
  cycle_length=2
)
```

Where I define `gen(...)` to take a value (which is a pointer to some data such as a filename which `gen` knows how to access).

This fails because `gen` receives a tensor object, not a python/numpy value.

> Is there a way to resolve the tensor object to a value inside of `gen(...)`?

The reason for interleaving the generators is so I can manipulate the list of data-pointers/filenames with other dataset operations such as `.shuffle()` and `.repeat()` without the need to bake those into the `gen(...)` function, which would be necessary if I started with the generator directly from the list of data-pointers/filenames.

I want to use the generator because a large number of data values will be generated per data-pointer/filename.

Comment: It appears that the answer here is no, there is tf.py_func which provides this functionality for the map functions, but tf.py_func doesn't work with generators. I'll leave this open a while longer in case any more information comes to light. This seems to be a tough limitation of the Dataset pipeline process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow now supports passing tensor arguments to the generator:

```
def map_func(tensor):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, tf.float32, args=(tensor,))
    return dataset
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer, I hadn't noticed that yet. This is very good news!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeed no. Here is a reference to a couple of relevant git issues (open as of the time of this writing) for further developments on the question:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13101

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16343