# Interleaving files with subprocess.Popen in tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have multiple files that I'd like to consume in tiny chunks until EOF with `tf.data` instead of using `tf.read_file` once per file (as some files are much bigger than others).

I don't know how to consume piped subprocesses as a TensorFlow op (`tf.py_func` somehow?), and the dataset element from `list_files` is only known during graph execution so the following doesn't work:

```
def stream(path, bytesize=2048):
    args = f'my_program {path}'
    with subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as pipe:
        while True:
            buffer = pipe.stdout.read(bytesize)
            yield np.frombuffer(buffer)
            if len(buffer) < bytesize:
                break


def map_func(path):
    generator = functools.partial(stream, path)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, tf.float32)
    return dataset


dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset
    .list_files('data/*')
    .interleave(map_func, batch_size)
    .batch(batch_size)
)
```

Is there some way of getting a dataset element's value into the iterable expected by `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` or am I going about this the wrong way?

Related: [Can the map function supplied to `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(...)` resolve a tensor object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48349409/7287271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow just got support for parameterised generators in tf.data!

```
def map_func(path):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(stream, tf.float32, args=(path,))
    return dataset
```

`pip install tf-nightly` or `tf-nightly-gpu` to try the above out.