# how to read .hdf5 datafile as input to a convolutional neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, hdf5, training-data, conv-neural-network

I have saved my large array of images and their labels in HDF5 format using this link:
[Saving and loading a large number of images (data) into a single HDF5 file](http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/data_preparation/hdf5/hdf5.html)
which gives me following keys.
list of datasets:

```
['test_img', 'test_labels', 'train_img', 'train_labels', 'train_mean', 'val_img', 'val_labels']
```

Now, I want to provide `training data` and `training labels` to a convolutional neural network (VGG-16 or ResNet) for training purpose and also want to validate and test my result using CNN. How can I input my data from HDF5 file into CNN?

Comment: Search for `load_model` and `load_weights` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this open-source project [tftables](https://github.com/ghcollin/tftables).

This other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48309631/tensorflow-tf-data-dataset-reading-large-hdf5-files) also has a great detailed answer by mikkola, explaining how to use your own generator with the new Tensorflow Dataset API otherwise.

Comment: The first link seems to work out but I have one more question will hdf5 table files and h5py files be dealt similarly ? can i use same method for h5py as well?

Comment: I am not aware of differences between hdf5 files created with h5py and with other tools, so I'd say the method should work with both; but it should be easy to quickly verify.